# Mule-Microsoft Service Bus : Azure Service BUS queue issue

Tags: mule, azure-servicebus-queues

I need to connect to Microsoft Service Bus queue from Mulesoft application. 
My configuration and everything looks fine. I can see the Test Connection was successful. But, after application is deployed, the folloing warning message keeps on coning in console :

```
org.mule.modules.microsoftservicebus.amqp.messaging.NoAcknowledgeMessageListenerContainer: Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue1' - trying to recover. Cause: It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver. TrackingId:xxx
```

I am new to Azure and have never implemented this with Mule. 
Any help will be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Cause: It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver.

The issue you're experiencing is most likely related to the fact that MuleSoft connector is non-sessioned, but the entity (queue) you have has [Sessions feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) enabled. Sessions allow FIFO pattern and guaranteed message order to be implemented, but require sessioned client connection.

I'm not familiar with the product, but it should be possible to configure MuleSoft to create a connector that supports sessions. Their [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/ms-service-bus-connector-reference) doesn't seem to suggest that it doesn't.

Note that a setting like Sessions support cannot be modified once it's set. Therefore you will need to drop the queue and re-create. In case that's the route you'll need to take, be careful to ensure there are no messages in-flights and that there are no active senders trying to send to the queue while you're applying changes.